# is there an easy way to inspect/edit values stored in nsIPrefBranch?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom

I'm looking for a way to quickly edit and view my extension credential list (I use nsIPrefBranch to store it).

Is there any easy way to do that? I tried to look where that's stored but couldnt find it.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Got it,
It's inside %appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles{ID}\prefs.js

Comment: Why not just use about:config?